# Symfony 4 DateTimeNormalizer Service not being applied

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am creating a normalizer and im not sure now it should be applied

"Custom normalizers and/or encoders can also be loaded by tagging them as serializer.normalizer and serializer.encoder. It's also possible to set the priority of the tag in order to decide the matching order."

https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#adding-normalizers-and-encoders

services.yml

```
datetime_normalizer:
    class: App\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer
    public: true
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

class

```
<?php
namespace App\Normalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

/**
 * Class DateTimeNormalizer
 */
class DateTimeNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
        return $object->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof \DateTime;
    }
}
```

call

```
 $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));

 $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);

 $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer]);

 $user = $serializer->normalize($token->getUser());
```

output

```
"datetime":{"timezone":{"name":"UTC","transitions":[{"ts":-9223372036854775808,"time":"-292277022657-01-27T08:29:52+0000","offset":0,"isdst":false,"abbr":"UTC"}],"location":{"country_code":"??","latitude":0,"longitude":0,"comments":""}},"offset":0,"timestamp":1527033600}
```

*full code at github*

https://github.com/ricardosaracino/symfony-pull-list/blob/master/config/services.yaml

Comment: you simply don't use it: `$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(...`

Comment: Why do you build your own `Serializer` instance and do not use the one that is provided by the framework as the `serializer` service?

Comment: @xabbuh, this is a basic example that demonstrates the issue. i have much more complex ones that i want to wire as services.. added a link to git

Comment: Still, if you do not use the `serializer` service, you will also have to register your custom normalizer yourself. The `serializer.normalizer` tag only affects the `Serializer` instance that is managed by the framework (and for which you have to make use of the `serializer` service). That's why I was asking why you created your custom `Serializer` instance.

Comment: ya, Titouan Galopin pointed me in the right direction.  i totally missed the `public function index(SerializerInterface $serializer)` part

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating your own serializer, you need to rely on the serializer created by Symfony by injecting it where you need. An example of this is in the doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-the-serializer-service.

Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services for controllers to learn more.

Comment: Im out right now so i cannot test till i get home, but I totally missed that injection .. (facepalm)

Comment: how would this work with the @Group Annotations, i can see them using it in the documentation. https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-serializer-improvements#added-a-constraintviolationlistnormalizer

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as "how would it work", it would simply work like expected :) (https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations)

Comment: I was just curious if i needed to do something to initialize the Normalizer with the ClassMetadataFactory `$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);`

Comment: No, not needed :) everything is prepared by Symfony you just need to use the annotations and the serializer provided by the framework.

Comment: papa bless it all works beautifully, simplifies my code so much ... thanks again
https://github.com/ricardosaracino/symfony-pull-list/commit/186a02dfe560b2c198add45ef9a8eda1193d953e